# Meteor: Managing Data Without a User Account (Yet)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an architectural/design decision to face.

I'm working on a Cordova/Meteor app which has a unique onboarding experience. A new user is treated to a wizard, which walks them through the steps of filling out some forms.

The flow of the wizard waits until the last step in order to register a user account. The challenge I have, is what to do with the form data prior  finalizing an account.

I need this data to follow through several pages, compounding in size through each page, and to finish it off by attaching it to a user object.

Ordinarily, my go-to would be to set Session variables and grab them all at the end. But since this is a phonegap app, I'm leery of relying on this too heavily because I've had some experiences--when turning the app off in the middle of the page that relies on Session--having issues when you come back to the app.

I'm considering making use of [persistent-session](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session/) because it sounds like it wouldn't have the weird turnoff effect I mentioned above.

I'm curious as to the insights of experienced Meteor developers. Do you have any recommendations to ferry the data along in an elegant, consistent matter all the way up to the last screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localSorage to persist the data, which won't be cleared by a browser refresh.

```
//set a value
Meteor._localStorage.setItem('key', value);

//get a value
var item = Meteor._localStorage.getItem('key');

//remove the item
Meteor._localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Comment: Looks like your suggestion is the same conclusion I came too, use localStorage -- which is what persistent session does. It's cool to see the "native" way to do it too.